# Why OpenGL uses column-major matrix order?

Tags: opengl, graphics

I know what is column-major and how to deal with it. Question what was there purpose to implement system in that way? Any technical or conceptual restricts?

Comment: `glUniformMatrix*` has a parameter to tell OpenGL which layout to use. So both, column-major and row-major should be possible.

Answer (score 10):

By arranging matrices like that in memory, you have immediate access to the column vectors (obviously). When using right associative multiplication (i.e. what OpenGL and most other graphics systems do to allow for the easy chaining of transformations) the column vectors of a matrix **are** the basis vectors of the coordinate system the matrix is mapping to.

And having easy access to these basis vectors is kind of useful for further graphics operations, like setting up mirroring planes, billboards, etc.

***TL;DR:** When doing graphics programming you often want to use the basis vectors of a transformation for other things. If right associative multiplication is used, the basis vectors are the columns of the transformation matrices.*

Comment: However, this SO question indicates that it's more cache-friendly to store a row-major format internally: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47190535/is-row-major-ordering-more-efficient-for-matrix-vector-multiplication

Comment: @AaronFranke: Yes, cache effects become apparent very quickly for larger matrices. However the feeble 4×4 matrices we deal with in graphics programming tend to fit entirely into the vector registers of modern CPUs, so what usually happens is, that first the whole matrix is prefetched as a whole and then the computations happen entirely on the registers. Compilers these days are smart enough to do exactly that for my linmath.h when compiling with -O2 or -O3.

Comment: @AaronFranke. Cache-friendlyness depends on how you use your data. If you mainly work column-by-column, use column major order. If you mainly work row-by-row, use row major order.